# How should I keep my unframed A3 size pencil drawings?

Tags: drawing, paper, storage

Just to protect my drawings from dust and smudging them, I used to keep my A4 size drawings in a office file like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXEU8.jpg).

[image]

Now, I've started drawing on A3 sized papers, and I don't know where to keep them. Shall I go with a similar file that I used to use, with a larger dimension, or is there some special file for keeping artworks? And how can I Google it (I tried, but found only office files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A3 Drawings Briefcase

[image]

[Google search link](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1901&bih=1219&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=Rx4BXay3Op6CjLsP2raWkA0&q=A3%20drawings%20briefcase&oq=A3%20drawings%20briefcase&gs_l=img.3...1147.28973..29440...0.0..0.675.1578.1j1j5-2......0....1j2..gws-wiz-img.......0i8i7i30.uiCbEAd26BQ#imgrc=_)

Comment: I need a long terms solution now :P What if we have 100+ drawings? We buy more briefcases? Wouldn't that be difficult to manage?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **flat file**, which is essentially a filing cabinet with wider shorter drawers. Also look at other types of **portfolios** that take up less space and cost less. There are also **museum boxes** which come in a lot of sizes. Having multiple boxes/envelopes/drawers also lets you organize your work instead of having one big pile of drawings.